# Cannot Connect to Azure ML after resetting Microsoft password

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to open VS code on Azure ML instance. It was working fine until recently I reset my Microsoft password. I tried to install Azure Account and Azure ML on VS code but I get the following error:

```
Settings sync cannot be turned on because the current version (1.57.1, 
507ce72a4466fbb27b715c3722558bb15afa9f48) is not compatible with the sync service. Please 
update before turning on sync. Operation Id: 35a43034ce7c4389bce5c70d2dc178e3
```

Do I need to reconfigure the ssh config again or is there any way out? Very new to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Azure VSCode extension installed? If so, I'd recommend calling the `Azure: Sign In` command to re-authenticate

Comment: Yes, I tried to close to the remote connection and sign in Azure Account from local VS code. Connected to my Azure ML instance and it works now.
Thanks Anders!!